# Proof that $a^{\tan x} + a^{\cot x} \leq 2a$ where $\frac{1}{2} \leq a \leq 1$ and $0 \leq x \leq \frac{\pi}{4}$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, inequality, contest-math, exponential-function

$a^{\tan x}+a^{\cot x} \leq 2a$ where $\frac{1}{2} \leq a \leq 1$ and $0 \leq x \leq \frac{\pi}{4}$

I would like to prove the inequality which is given above. I spent all day thinking about it - I tried some inequalities like relation between exponential and linear or Jensen, but it doesn't work. I tried also by calculus - but when we calculate the derivative and assume it is equal to 0 we have an equality which isn't easy to solve. Maybe anyone has an idea, maybe it's easy and I don't know why I have a problem... I would be grateful if you gave me a hint, I don't want a full solution :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we set $\tan(x)=z$ we have $z\in [0,1]$ and we may find the maximum of 
$$ f(a)=a^{z-1} + a^{\frac{1}{z}-1} $$
over the interval $a\in\left[\frac{1}{2},1\right]$. Since the given function is convex (it is the sum of two convex functions) the maximum is attained at the boundary. At $a=1$ we have $f(a)=2$ and at $a=\frac{1}{2}$ we have
$$ f(a) = \frac{2}{2^{z}}+\frac{2}{2^{1/z}}\leq 2 $$
hence $f(a)\leq 2$ as wanted.

Comment: How do we prove that $f(a)$ is convex in $a$ for all values of $z$?

Comment: "At a=1 we have f(a)=1 " --> no, we have f(1) = 2.

Comment: @Andreas: typo fixed.

Comment: @MartinR: I am claiming what I am claiming, i.e. that $f(a)$ is convex on $[1/2,1]$. That can be checked by computing $f''(a)$ for instance.

Comment: I do see now why $f''(a) \ge 0$, but not yet why $f(1/2) \le 2$.

Comment: @MartinR: the function $g(z)=2^{1-z}+2^{1-1/z}$ has a unique stationary point in $(0,1)$ and it is an absolute minimum. It follows that the maximum value of $g(z)$ on $[0,1]$ is attained at the boundary and it equals $2$.

Comment: @jpatrick: it is.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Ok, I can't see it from form of second derivative (we know that $a \geq \frac{1}{2}$, no z) but I know that sum of convex function is convex. You're right. But if I would like to consider $a\in (0,\frac{1}{2}]$,which is given - this function is also convex at this interval, but for this $a$'s we have maximum equal 1 - it's easy to show and you can look on the plot for arbitrary $a$ in this interval... Why this reasoning isn't correct for interval given above?

Comment: @jpatrick: honestly I cannot understand your issue. My approach above proves that is is enough to show that $2^{-z}+2^{-1/z}\leq 1$ holds for any $z\in[0,1]$. That is pretty simple.

Comment: You're right! I see it. It's obvious. Thanks. :)